# How to receive continues real time accelerometer data from Apple Watch

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I would like to know if I can create an apple watch app that will send me continues realtime accelerometer data to my iPhone app for a long period (30 min for example). I know how to read acceleration data when the apple watch app is active, but how can I read and send this data when the app is not active (in background)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `watchOS 2` , `WatchConnectivity` framework is available for sending data between `Watch` and `iPhone` app. It has all options available either you want to send data when your companion iPhone app is active or you can also send data in background.
For more about watchConnectivity check this video. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-713/

Comment: I know how to send data to the iPhone app, my problem is how to keep the accelerometer sensor working when the apple watch app is not active

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361439/apple-watchos-2-accelerometer

Answer (score 1):

Use HKWorkouSession to ensure that your app is still running even the screen locks or in the background.

> Running in the Background
>   Workout sessions also allow your app to continue running in the background. Background execution grants an app the following abilities:
>   The app continues to run throughout the entire workout session, even when the user lowers their wrist or interacts with a different app. When the user raises their wrist, the app reappears, letting the user quickly and easily check their current progress and performance.
>   The app can continue to access data from Apple Watch’s sensors in the background, letting you keep the app up to date at all times. For example, a running app can continue to track the user’s heart rate, ensuring that the most recent heart rate data is displayed whenever the user raises their wrist.
>   The app can alert the user using audio or haptic feedback while running in the background.
>   Ref: [HKWorkouSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutsession)

Code sample below from Apple's SwingWatch demo:

```
// MARK: Properties
let motionManager = MotionManager()
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

weak var delegate: WorkoutManagerDelegate?
var session: HKWorkoutSession?

// MARK: Initialization

init() {
    motionManager.delegate = self
}

// MARK: WorkoutManager

func startWorkout() {
    // If we have already started the workout, then do nothing.
    if (session != nil) {
        return
    }

    // Configure the workout session.
    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .tennis
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .outdoor

    do {
        session = try HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Unable to create the workout session!")
    }

    // Start the workout session and device motion updates.
    healthStore.start(session!)
    motionManager.startUpdates()
}

func stopWorkout() {
    // If we have already stopped the workout, then do nothing.
    if (session == nil) {
        return
    }

    // Stop the device motion updates and workout session.
    motionManager.stopUpdates()
    healthStore.end(session!)

    // Clear the workout session.
    session = nil
}
```